My create page in InventoryController is getting an error by the _Layout in ASP.NET Core MVC
I'm trying to create a item but it says the
Layout = _DashboardLayout

in Dashboard/Inventory/Create.cshtml is my problem but I can't see any problem here except what I am doing with InventoryController.
Here is the error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Dashboard_Inventory_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml
...

It is somehow related to this one but kinda different because the _DashboardLayout was the problem.
ASP.NET Core NullReferenceException when just accessing model
Here is the code of my InventoryController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Gravitywears.Entities;
using Gravitywears.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gravitywears.Controllers.Dashboard
{
    // [Route("Dashboard/[controller]")]
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public InventoryController(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // ...

        [HttpPost("Dashboard/Inventory/Create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,ProductName,ProductBrand,Quantity,TypeOfProduct,Price,AgeRange")] Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Add(product);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Product successfully created!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter a unique inputs.");
                    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Inventory/Create.cshtml", product);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed; redisplay form
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Failed to create product. Please check the form and try again.";
            return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Inventory/Create.cshtml", product);
        }
    }
}

And this is the Create.cshtml view:
@{
    Layout = "_DashboardLayout"; // Use the layout for consistent design
}

@model Gravitywears.Models.Product
                
<form asp-controller="Inventory" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="inv-cp-ppqty">
                    <div class="image">
                        <label for="imageUpload">
                            <svg id="imageLabel" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                            </svg>
                            <img id="imagePreview"
                                style="display: none; max-width: 100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 10px;" />
                        </label>
                        @* <input asp-for="Image" type="file" id="imageUpload" name="Image" required
                        onchange="previewImage(event)" /> *@

                        @* <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span> *@

                        @* <img src="" alt=""> *@
                    </div>
                    <div class="fill-inv">
                        <div class="inp-inv">
                            <input asp-for="ProductName" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-inv">
                            <input asp-for="ProductBrand" type="text" placeholder="Product Brand" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProductBrand" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-inv">
                            <input asp-for="Quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" min="1" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-inv">
                            <select asp-for="TypeOfProduct" id="typeOfProduct" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" disabled selected> Type of Product </option>
                                <option value="Cloth"> Cloth </option>
                                <option value="Pants"> Pants </option>
                                <option value="Accessories"> Accessories </option>
                                <option value="SportsGear"> Sports Gear </option>
                                <!-- Add more options as needed -->
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="TypeOfProduct" class="text-danger"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-inv">
                            <select asp-for="AgeRange" id="ageRange" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" disabled selected> Age </option>
                                <option value="Kids"> -18 </option>
                                <option value="Adults"> 18+ </option>
                                <!-- Add more options as needed -->
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="AgeRange" class="text-danger"></span>

                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="button-type">
                            <h5> Create Item </h5>
                        </button>
                    </div>
</form>

I'm only expecting that the create will pass through the asp-for , asp-validation-for and other else attributes. And also it will pass now to my database.
But since the error was something about the Layout but I don't know what I'm gonna do about it for now.

See circled code... here it seems like you are redirecting to Create, but you're not passing along the model.
You should consider putting a breakpoint (press F9) at if (ModelState.IsValid) and debug from there.  product may also be null.
debugging is your friend.


thanks but where do I debugging? I don't know if I can debugging in vscode since the only thing I can do is dotnet build to find the bug but can't no error seems to found.

I use VS 2022 for that.  I am not certain if there is an extension in VS Code that accomplishes the same thing... perhaps someone could say.
there are free / community editions of the tools available.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Firstly you need read the article that how to debug the source code in Visual Studio Code.
Then A NullReferenceException exception is thrown when you try to access a member on a type whose value is null. But for your shared view code, it seems you do not read any value. Maybe you do not share the whole code.
Please check the TempData if it is null or not. You can add an if clause to judge the TempData to prevent NullReferenceException. Also check if you use @Model.PropertyName in your view.
